# Scripting functoid returns input instead of return-value in Biztalk mapper

Tags: c#, .net, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I have a scripting functoid with the following code:

```
public string MyConcat(string product)
{
    string retStr= "01";
    product = product.ToUpper();
    if(product.Contains("CONDITION")){
        retStr= "02";
    }
    return retStr;
}
```

This works perfect when I run it in LinqPad, but when I test the map it returns the product string instead of the retStr, which I find really weird. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Inline C# Script Type don't you? The script works perfect testing a BizTalk map, maybe you have some cached version or you have an old DLL in the GAC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have another Scripting functoid that has the same signature, i.e. is called  MyConcat, returns a string, has a single string input.  In that case it will execute the first version created with the input linked to it.

Please make sure you give your function names a unique and descriptive name to avoid this.

If you do need to use the same function multiple times in your map, this feature of it re-using the the function is quite useful, but I usually make sure to add a comment to all the subsequent copies stating that only the first version has the code.